# SFDC application asking for 2 step verification for each Selenium Run

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

Currently I am working on some Automation testing on Salesforce using Selenium webdriver.Salesforce system asks for a two step verification code(mobile/email OTP) apart from the usual credentials.Now, once you verify the user with the OTP, the application supposedly saves it in the cookies. So, from next instances only user id-pwd combination is sufficient to logon.

So, for that I have created a custom profile in firefox and tried to launch it through my code.But each time I am running it, a new temp profile is getting created where the cookie details are not saved already.

This is the snippet of the code:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("SFDC");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

When I am trying to log in manually this(2 step verification) is not happening.The automated execution was working properly before 27th Jan.
Can you please help?

Comment: And do you know what has changed since 27th Jan? There was a Firefox update recently...

Comment: You can run any Firefox / FirefoxDriver you like (well, more or less). Have you logged the names/values of the cookies you're getting now, then downgraded, re-run, and compared the two?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this post in the Salesforce Stack Exchange: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107027/selenium-testing-two-factor-authentication-problems/107368

There they have a solution where you can disable the 2-factor authentication by white-listing your IP in Salesforce. It worked for me.